# Update a document and return the updated document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

```
const _id = req.params.id;
let tire = await TireModel.findOne({ _id });
tire = await tire.update({description : "new description"});
console.log(tire);
```

When I run this piece of code, I want the tire to be the updated one, but instead it returns the result of the operation in the database. I already tried the {new: true} option.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `findOneAndUpdate()` function.

```
const filter = { name: 'Jean-Luc Picard' };
const update = { age: 59 };

// `doc` is the document _after_ `update` was applied because of
// `new: true`
let doc = await Character.findOneAndUpdate(filter, update, {
  new: true
});
doc.name; // 'Jean-Luc Picard'
doc.age; // 59
```

More information https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/findoneandupdate.html

Comment: I already know that way, but what if I previously made the document query and stored it in a varibale and I want to use update. This document does not have the findOneAndUpdate method.

Answer (score 2):

After you find your document with `findOne`, you can update it's fields, and then use `save()` method:

```js
const _id = req.params.id;
let tire = await TireModel.findOne({ _id });

if (tire) {
  tire.description = "new description";
  tire = await tire.save();
  console.log(tire);
} else {
  //todo
}
```